# what actually it is doing (data=request.data)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
def post(self,request):
        serializer=NameSerializers(data=request.data)
        if(serializer.is_valid):
            name=serializer.data.get('name')

            msg='hello {} Wish you happy New Year'.format(name)
            return Response({'msg':msg})
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=400)
```

My questions are:

1. Is `data=request.data` getting the data the client app has been sending in JSON?
2. Is `serializer.is_valid` an in-built function of serializer class to check the data we have received is valid data or not?
3. What is `serializer.data.get('name')` doing?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. A good starting point might be reading https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/.

Answer (score 1):

1. `request.data` is basically data sent in the request body from the client.
2. `serializer.is_valid()`, yes, it is a function to check data received from the request, you can pass `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` to raise an exception in case of invalid data received.
3. `serializer.data` is a python dictionary which is being saved in the model, so `.get('var_name')` is actually accessing the value from the dictionary.

Hope this helps :) Happy Coding